# ASP.NET Core 3.1 create a service to send email confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I call the method `EmailConfirmation` on several pages so I decided to create a service for this.

But I have a problem with `GetEmailConfirmCallback`: `Url` is null.

I would like to change Identity area pages also and use this service instead of in some pages like register and externalLogin,... each time do the same task.

This is my class:

```
public class ApplicationServices : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public ApplicationServices(IEmailSender emailSender, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public async Task<ResultModel> EmailConfirmation(ApplicationUser user, string returnUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login")
    {
        ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();

        try
        {
            var pathToEmailTemplate = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath
            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
            + "templates"
            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
            + "email_templates"
            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
            + "confirm-email-reset-password.html";

            string emailTemplateString = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToEmailTemplate))
            {
                emailTemplateString = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string messageSubject = "Confirm your email";
            string messageBody = $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(await GetEmailConfirmCallback(user, returnUrl))}'>clicking here</a>.";

            string messageSenderName = "Support team.";

            string emailMessage = string.Format(emailTemplateString, messageSubject, string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FullName) ? user.FullName : "User", messageBody, messageSenderName);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, messageSubject, emailMessage);

            resultModel.IsSucceed = true;
            return resultModel;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            resultModel.IsSucceed = false;
            resultModel.Message = e.Message;
            return resultModel;
        }
    }
    
    private async Task<string> GetEmailConfirmCallback(ApplicationUser user, string returnUrl)
    {
        var codeEmail = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        codeEmail = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeEmail));
        var callbackUrlEmail = Url.Page(
        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
        pageHandler: null,
        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = codeEmail, returnUrl },
        protocol: Request.Scheme);

        return callbackUrlEmail;
    }
}
```

[image: Debug image 1]

[image: Debug image 2]

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use your debugger. If you haven't used your debugger, **why not**?

Comment: Thanks for your comment I'm using the debugger and Url is null but in Register.cshtml.cs it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register `HttpContextAccessor` in Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

2. Add `IHttpContextAccessor` and `LinkGenerator` as dependency injections in the service class

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
private readonly LinkGenerator _generator;

public ApplicationServices(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                            IEmailSender emailSender, 
                            IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, 
                            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
                            LinkGenerator generator)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    _generator = generator;
}
```

3. Change method `GetEmailConfirmCallback`

```
private async Task<string> GetEmailConfirmCallback(ApplicationUser user, HttpContext context, string returnUrl)
{
    var codeEmail = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    codeEmail = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeEmail));


    var callbackUrlEmail = _generator.GetUriByPage(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,
    page:"/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    handler: null,
    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = codeEmail, returnUrl });


    return callbackUrlEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Url.Action` instead of `Url.Page`? `Url.Action` is for MVC and `Url.Page` is for Razor. You are not specifying if you are using Razor or MVC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm trying to call `EmailConfirmation` from the razor pages, and the controllers. I added `ApplicationServices` to `startup.cs` and with dependency injection, I would like to access this class everywhere in all areas Identity that was made by scaffold and another area I created based on the MVC.

Comment: I changed my code as you said `Url.Action` but the error is the same because Url is null.

Comment: If you are using Razor, you should use `Url.Page`. If you can update your code sample with your implementation of `startup.cs` and `EmailSender` class, perhaps we can help find the problem.

Comment: I solved my issue with passing HttpContext from controllers or razor pages to `EmailConfirmation` method. And instead `Url` I used string format to create a callback URL. Maybe it is not a professional way but it works for now and later I will improve the code. Thanks to all commenters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are some detail from the past link

They used a URL.Action like this example:
[image]

In your code you're using Url.Page.

This is other exmaple that uses Url.Action:
[image]

Comment: I changed my code as you said `Url.Action` but the error is the same because Url is null.